# Alloy user interface (access a tag value)

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I'm working with liferay portal 6.2. And I want to get the value of the text in a tag with alloy user interface.
exemple:

```
<div> 
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    "value"
</div>
```

the desired result is: value

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlloyUI, being an extension of YUI3, uses get/set methods to access and manipulate the properties/attributes of the object ([YUI3 Node](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_get) / [AlloyUI Node](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Node.html)) that is returned when looking up elements from the page.

Some examples can be reviewed in [this documentation](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/node/) as well as [this documentation](http://www.liferay.com/web/nathan.cavanaugh/blog/-/blogs/alloyui-working-with-elements-and-events).

In general you'll need something unique (i.e. id, css class) to the `div` in order to fetch only that element. Once you have that element, `divNode.get('text')` will give you all of the text within the element.  There is not a means to easily "skip" the paragraph contents within the `div` without the `value` being contained within some other markup. If you have control over the markup and can do this, that would be the best option. Otherwise you are left to using the [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function to strip out the paragraph contents from the text.

```
<script>
  AUI().use('aui-base', function(A) {

   var paragraphText = A.one('#myDiv>p').get('text');
   var divText = A.one('#myDiv').get('text')

   var onlyValue = divText.replace(paragraphText, "").trim()
   console.log(onlyValue)

  })
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. this helped me a lot. but the method get('text') was enough to skip the paragraph. ie: A.one('#myDiv').get('text') returns value.